# how to i change the vertical position and size of bar button Item in may navigation controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uinavigationitem

I am working on a project, i have a navigation bar of height 129 now I need to add a bar button Item to my navigation bar. 
My problem is with the bar button position i want to change the position of bar button item.

This is an image of what is happening:
[image]

This shows the position for where i want it:
[image]

Comment: Dont change the bar height, use different view for the bar (in your nav controller) and hide the bar away

Comment: I tried doing that i am actually using SWrevealController to make a split view. I tried using a view and adding a button to the view to toggle between the rear view and front view but it doesnot seem to work.
@Tj3n

Answer (score 1):

Very specific situation but you can try set image insets for bar button item.

```
 let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")     
 let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.leftButtonDidPressed))
 leftButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 64)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Comment: That would not change the touch area.

Comment: There is can be trick with adding gesture to navigationController.navigationBar and handle touches. But it depends on task

Comment: @meaning-matters is right it doesnot change the touch area.
Instead of a navbar button can't i use a button to toggle between the rear view and front view (i am using swreveal view controller)
**open.target(forAction:#selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), withSender: self)** 
i used above code but it is not working.open is a button.@DmitryMolokov

Comment: **buttonHamburger.target = self.revealViewController()
        buttonHamburger.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))** this is working. here buttonHamburger is a nav bar button